# ¿Cómo quito con regex patrón de símbolos #<@! XXXX>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, discord.py

¿Saben cómo partiendo de una string con el tageo, como en este caso `'#<@!808947310809317387> tr: the planes can fly high'` poder quitar todos los tags y dejar solo la frase (que es lo importante)? O sea, quitar todo lo que esté entre `#<@!  >` y esos símbolos también.
La idea sería que quedase por ejemplo `'tr: the planes can fly high'` en lugar de todo lo otro.

O por ejemplo de tener `'tr: Military trains are very heavy but still very fast #<@!808947310809317387>'` y poder quitar eso y quedarme tan solo con `'tr: Military trains are very heavy but still very fast'`

Si bien se suele tagear al principio, también puede hacer en otras partes de la cadena o dejando o no espacios, entonces la idea es que lo quite/filtre sin importar la posición o las veces que aparezca en la cadena de inicio.

Acá una parte del código:

```py
        input_text_for_regex = input_text.lower()

        trad_bool = False

        regex = re.compile(r'((tr:)|(traduce lo siguiente:)|(traduce lo siguiente)|(traduce esto:)|(traduce esto)|(translate that:)|(translate that)|(usa tu traductor:)|(usa tu traductor)|(usa el traductor:)|(usa el traductor)|(use the translator:)|(use the translator)|(use translator:)|(use translator)|(use your translator:)|(use your translator)\s+)')
        #<@!808947310809317387> tr: Planes
        

        if regex.match(input_text_for_regex):
            
            #print("debe traducir...")

            trad_bool = True

            try:

                input_text = re.sub(regex, "" ,input_text).strip()

            
                translator = Translator() #Creo el objeto de la clase Translator()

                src_lang = translator.detect(input_text).lang
                #print(src_lang)

                input_text = translator.translate(text=input_text, src=src_lang, dest="spanish") #Del idioma sea cual sea que detecte lo pasa a español
                input_text = input_text.text
                #print(input_text)
```

---

Editada, esto da error pero queda salvado por la excepción:

```py
    def process(self, **kwargs) -> str:
        input_text = kwargs["InputText"]
        user_text = kwargs["UserText"]
        user_data = kwargs["UserData"]

        input_text_for_regex = input_text.lower()

        trad_bool = False

        regex = re.compile(r'((tr:)|(traduce lo siguiente:)|(traduce lo siguiente)|(traduce esto:)|(traduce esto)|(translate that:)|(translate that)|(usa tu traductor:)|(usa tu traductor)|(usa el traductor:)|(usa el traductor)|(use the translator:)|(use the translator)|(use translator:)|(use translator)|(use your translator:)|(use your translator)\s+)')
        #regex2 = re.compile(r'<\D{,2}\d+>\s{,1}')

        if regex.match(input_text_for_regex): #verificamos si hay concidencia
            
            #print("debe traducir...")

            trad_bool = True

            try:

                input_text = re.sub(regex, "" ,input_text).strip()
                #input_text = " ".join(regex2.split(input_text)[1:])

            
                translator = Translator() #Creo el objeto de la clase Translator()

                src_lang = translator.detect(input_text).lang
                #print(src_lang)

                input_text = translator.translate(text=input_text, src=src_lang, dest="spanish") #Del idioma sea cual sea que detecte lo pasa a español
                input_text = input_text.text
                #print(input_text)

                #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                text = self.chatbot.generator(input_text)
                self.learn(user_text, user_data["info"])

                if not re.search("[a-zA-Z]", text):
                    text = "NoContext"

                text = self.replace_labels(text, self.chatbot.json_dict["structures"])
                text = self.replace_labels(text, user_data["info"])

                #print(type(input_text))  # Devolvera <class 'str'>
                #text = input_text  #Test INPUT, donde te contesta exactamente lo que le escribes

                #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

                #La función requiere 2 parámetros, y si la función tiene un return, debes hacer una asignación para recogerlo por eso las iguale a una variable
                text = direct_election(input_text, text)
                text = inverse_election(input_text, text)

                text = net_test(input_text, text)
                
                #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
            except:
                answer_num = random.randint(1, 3) #numero inicial y final del rango del cual queremos generar numeros

                if answer_num == 1:
                    text = "Aparentemente algo fallo con la API del traductor o quizas sea algo con mi internet por lo que creo que debería intentar controlar el estado de mi conexión"
                elif answer_num == 2:
                    text = "Ouu vaya creo que hubo un problema con la API del traductor o quizas no tengo una buena conexión, creo que de momento no podre hablar en varios idiomas hasta poder usar el traductor"
                elif answer_num == 3:
                    text = "Vaya, creo que surgio un error al intentar usar la API del traductor o quizas sea un problema en la conexión, la verdad no estoy segura, pero lo que si es seguro es que no podre utilizar la API del traductor por ahora"



        else:

            #print("no traduce")

            trad_bool = False

            #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            text = self.chatbot.generator(input_text)
            self.learn(user_text, user_data["info"])

            if not re.search("[a-zA-Z]", text):
                text = "NoContext"

            text = self.replace_labels(text, self.chatbot.json_dict["structures"])
            text = self.replace_labels(text, user_data["info"])

            #print(type(input_text))  # Devolvera <class 'str'>
            #text = input_text  #Test INPUT, donde te contesta exactamente lo que le escribes

            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            #La función requiere 2 parámetros, y si la función tiene un return, debes hacer una asignación para recogerlo por eso las iguale a una variable
            text = direct_election(input_text, text)
            text = inverse_election(input_text, text)

            text = net_test(input_text, text)
            
            #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        try:
            if trad_bool == True:
                
                text = translator.translate(text=text, src="spanish", dest=src_lang) #Del español que es el idioma nativo del bot lo pasa al idioma del input_text que recibio del usuario
                text = text.text

                return text #text = "esto es lo que devuelvo" #Test OUTPUT

            else:
                return text #text = "esto es lo que devuelvo" #Test OUTPUT
        except:
            return text
```

Comment: Tienes que definir cuales son "todos los tags". Pones un ejemplo, pero ¿cuantos tags pueden venir?¿en qué formato?

Comment: algo interesante que veo es que quieres traducir, pero necesitas que el usuario ponga algo referente a *traducir esto..*  te sugiero que investigues sobre *NLP*(Natural Language Procesing) o Procesamiento de Lenguaje Natural, Es un tipo de Red Neuronal, si lo aplicas a tu bot, será sorprendente :D

Comment: es que es un bot de discord y esta andando bien pero las traducciones fallan por culpa de los tags, el code del bot completo es realmente muy largo pero me esta faltando esta parte de quitar el tr: que es el activador del traductor y que debo quitar para obtener la frase pura y ahora tambien el tag porque interfiere por alguna razon severamente con la calidad de las traducciones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede utilizar la función `split()` del modulo `re`

```
import re

cadena = "<@!808947310809317387> tr: the planes can fly high'"
#creamos la expresion regular
regex = re.compile(r'<\D{,2}\d+>\s{,1}')

#separamos y cogemos todo desde la poscion 1 hasta el final
separado = regex.split(cadena)[1:]
print(separado)
```

**salida**

```
["tr: the planes can fly high'"]
```

si quieres obtenerlo como una cadena podemos usar el  método `join()`

```
separado = " ".join(regex.split(cadena)[1:])
print(separado)
#salida-> tr: the planes can fly high'
```

Si solo quieres obtener el texto que va después de `tr:`  pueddes usar la siguiente expresión regular

```py
regex = re.compile(r'<\D{,2}\d+>\s{,1}tr:\s{,}')

separado = " ".join(regex.split(cadena)[1:])
separado = " ".join(regex.split(cadena)[1:])
```

**salida**

```
the planes can fly high'
```

Comment: esta regex  re.compile(r'<\D{,2}\d+>\s{,1}') se puede agregar detras de esta otro         regex = re.compile(r'((tr:)|(traduce lo siguiente:)|(traduce lo siguiente)|(traduce esto:)|(traduce esto)|(translate that:)|(translate that)|(usa tu traductor:)|(usa tu traductor)|(usa el traductor:)|(usa el traductor)|(use the translator:)|(use the translator)|(use translator:)|(use translator)|(use your translator:)|(use your translator)\s+)')
porque necesito a ambas?

Comment: heem.. sip, mas bien la regex se puede simplificar para solo obtener la frase, ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: el tema es que yo necesito la primera regex que es la para quitar el tr:  y luego otra para quitar el tag en los casos en los que sea necesario

Comment: Haa... pues primero aplicas la expresión regular para quitar el `tr: ` y luego aplicas la que quita el *tag* sugiero que hagas otra pregunta pues lo que quieres es muy diferente a lo que preguntas y mi respuesta resuelve tu pregunta

Comment: Mira ahi si quieres pongo como quedo yo necesito que la nueva regex se adapte al code que tengo (ahi el problema de la pregunta) porque sino es quitar un problema para tener el otro. De todos modos estube viendo y me quedo como lo pondre en la version editada de mi pregunta aunque eso da error

Comment: ok mejor añádelo a la pregunta

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta y puse el code como editado, la parte importante esta en el regex y regex2 , que este ultimo esta comentado porque es el que da error por algun tema con la regex de quitar el tag supongo

Comment: Lo que esta dando problema es donde y como poner esa segunda regex, no la de quitar el "tr:" sino la de quitar el tag, la primera es que cada texto debe tener tr: para que se active el traductor y pase el if luego de eso la regex corta esa subcadena, pero ahora necesito que aparte de cortar ese tr: corte tambien esos simbolos del tag que afectan a la traduccion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126522/discussion-between-christian-and-electrisik-vocal).

Comment: Ok me parece bien